# How to use the microphone's intensity in Android? (voice)

Tags: android, voice, microphone, audiorecord

I need to implement into my app a functionality where works or needs to read the intensity of the voice through the microphone. But I don't know how to do it, can someone help me please? Just I need to read the intensity of the voice, not recognize any word.

I understand that I have to use [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class but I don't undestant whats steps I must write into my code, because I don't know if really necessary that I save a little of the voice into the SD card an after that convert it to PCM an after read the maximum of this signal.

Comment: By intensity do you mean volume (amplitude) or frequency or some combination?

Answer (score 2):

The AudioRecord class will let you record into a buffer.  You can then chose to process the buffer or save it to the SD card, depending on your needs.  Which you want to do depends entirely on your application.  Do you need the data after you process it?  Or is the processed result all you need?  Do you intend to play back the recordings?

A simplified example of how to use the AudioRecord class follows:

```
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

recorder.startRecording();

short buf[] = new short[buffersize];
int n = 0;
while(<some condition>) {
   n = recorder.read(buf, 0, bufferSize);
   process(buf);
}

recorder.stop();
recorder.release();
```

You would obviously want to put the above code in a thread outside of the main UI thread.

You need to make sure that whatever you do in process is quick enough that you can get back around to reading the data before the buffer fills up, or you will drop data.  Sample rate and buffer size will depend on how you are processing the data and what your latency requirements are.

After you get all that working, you may decide that you want to put the phone into 'Speaker Phone' in order to get better gain through the mic:

```
AudioManager amAudioManager;  
amAudioManager =      (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
amAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Yes, you have to put the phone in IN_CALL in order to enable the speaker phone.  Yes, some phones apparently disable the ability to record when IN_CALL.